# ¿Es posible hacer una conexión a una base de datos MYSQL con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mysql, mysqli

Me gustaría saber si es posible hacer una conexión a una base de datos MYSQL con javascript

GRACIAS!

Comment: deberías definir mejor la pregunta, ¿del lado del cliente o del servidor?¿Con qué fin?

Comment: Coincido con @ReneLimon. ¿ Cliente o servidor ? Voto por cerrarla.

Comment: del lado del cliente para hacer una consulta y mostrar los datos de esta

Answer (score 1):

Es posible, utilizando tecnologías **JavaScript** como `NodeJS` + `Express JS`.
Podrías fijarte en éste tutorial:

> https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible, usando algun lenguaje de lado del servidor que SI puede estar basado en JavaScript como lo es por ejemplo NodeJS, te recomiendo crear una REST API en el servidor y con AJAX hacerle requests, de tipo get o post y asi obtener la informacion.

Answer (score 0):

**Sí**, es posible!

Desde `MySQL 5.7`, existe un nuevo plugin llamado [MySQL HTTP Plugin](http://labs.mysql.com/), cual se puede añadir una interface `HTTP` a `MySQL`.

Hay tres API: `SQL` simple sobre `HTTP`, `CRUD` y `DOCUMENT` y los tres devuelven `JSON`, ósea, ideal para poder trabajar con `javascript` (del lado del cliente).

**Pero ójo:** Aún esta en estado: `Labs release`, pero seguro que pronto cambiará el estado de desarrollo!

```
  Sin HTTP Plugin      |    Con HTTP Plugin
--------------------------------------------
    HTTP Client               HTTP Client
        |                         |
   Web Service                    |
 (e.g. PHP script)                |
    Web server                    |
        |                    HTTP Plugin
      MySQL                     MySQL
```

[Información general - HTTP Plugin for MySQL](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/downloads/http_plugin_for_mysql_preview.pdf)